# file_get_contents() ssl operation failed from my own server only

Tags: php, https

I’ve been trying to access a HTML page on my own server over HTTPS. So script returns following errors:

PHP Version is 5.6.38

> Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1.
>   OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL
>   routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in
>   /home/user/public_html/index.php on line 11
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in
>   /home/user/public_html/index.php on line 11
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(https://myniceurl.com/file.html): failed to
>   open stream: operation failed in /home/user/public_html/index.php on
>   line 11

```
<?php

$contextOptions = [
    'ssl' => [
        'verify_peer' => true,
        'cafile' => '/etc/pki/tls/cert.pem',
    ]
];
$context = stream_context_create($contextOptions);

$data = file_get_contents('https://myniceurl.com/file.html', false, $context);
```

I've tried many solutions from different forums, but none helped. When I try to fetch a page from other sites over HTTPS it works, even I tried to fetch (over HTTPS) the same HTML page on my local machine, it worked properly. I thought the server cannot communicate itself. For investigation purposes, I changed HTTP and it worked properly.

I have tried so far:

1. Downloaded certificate bundle, added it `php.ini` file
2. `verify_peer = true` and CAfile for `stream_context_create`

I also confirm that `allow_url_fopen` is working. Due to the specialized nature of this problem; I’m not finding a lot of information for help. Have any of you come across something like this? Thanks.

Comment: what's on line 11 ??? seems to me your connexion succeeded, but some action in `index.php` is not correctly performed when coming from https.

Comment: Are you using a very old PHP version?

Comment: <?php

$contextOptions = [
    'ssl' => [
        'verify_peer' => true,
        'cafile' => '/etc/pki/tls/cert.pem',
    ]
];
$context = stream_context_create($contextOptions);

$data = file_get_contents('https://URL', false, $context); $data is the line 11 @YvesLeBorg

Comment: PHP Version is  5.6.38 @ÁlvaroGonzález

Comment: Possibility 1: You use a different hostname than what the certifcate uses. Possibility 2: The file cert.pem does not actually contain the CA that your certificate was signed by.

Comment: My certificate issued by Cloudflare for domain.com and *.domain.com. I am running the script under a subdomain. I have to mention that I put certificate bundle from https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html address. Should I use Cloudflare signed certificate? @NineBerry Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reason why this is not working.

It was because of Cloudflare  SSL/TLS encryption mode. My selected option was Full strict.

[image: Cloudflare]

As seen from the image the request has to hit Cloudflare request first, then Cloudflare forwards it to the origin server. However, I added my IP address and hostname to `/etc/hosts` file, that is why the request was not going out from my network and it causes SSL verification problems.